# Join local table with linked table

Tags: mysql, ms-access, ms-access-2016

I have a help desk system that uses a MySQL database and I've linked to some of its tables from Access 2016.  I also created a local table in the Access DB that contains some fields for management to add info such as comments, priority, target date and a few others and linked it to the main 'ticket' table's ID I brought in from MySQL.  What I'd like to do is pull in the ticket data (read-only) and display it on a form with my local table data (writable) so management can track the status of the tickets.  Here's the property sheet of the query:

Record Locks = Edited Record
Recordset Type = Dynaset (Inconsistent Updates)

So, the linked table 'Tickets' is left joined to my comments table (comments table has tickets' ID). When I run the query (which includes fields from both the local and linked tables) I can add info into the fields from the local table, and a record is created in that local table but the ID from the linked table (tickets) is not written to the local table (comments) although a sub record is created (the record in the local table has a 'plus' sing that opens what I assume is the record from the MySQL DB.

I tried using a one-to-one relationship (which is the most there should ever be) but I don't get anything because the local table doesn't have any records yet.

Hopefully I'm overlooking something simple..

Comment: `because the local table doesn't have any records yet`... If you do not have any recordset then how you will link? Joins will work same as local tables for linked tables.

Comment: I tested this and it works for me. However, a form/subform arrangement might be better. I left defaults for RecordLocks and RecordsetType.

Comment: Thanks Harun & Bill.. Harun: Yes the local table has a record (with my cmment) but the ID of the Linked table record wasn't written to the local table (when I leave the query and rerun it the local data doesn't return).